# Mutex not actually being released?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, mutex

I have a web api controller that I want to restrict it to run only once at a time. If a new request comes I want it to be rejected and not queued. I've implemented this behaviour using a Mutex, like in the following code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    string token = Utils.GetCurrentToken(RequestContext);
    //Some irrelevant code

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var mutexName = Utils.GetDBFromToken(token).ProjectID.ToString();

        var success = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(mutexName, out Mutex mutex);
        if (!success || mutex == null)
        {
            mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName);
            Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - Mutex created");
        }
        else
        {
            Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - Mutex exists");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();

            try
            {
                Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - Job started");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - Job ended");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - About to release mutex");
            if (mutex != null)
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                mutex.Close();
                mutex.Dispose();
                Utils.Log(token, mutexName + " - Mutex released");
            }
        }
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

Now if I call the controller 3 times in success, I get the following logs, which is exactly what I expected:

```
2018-10-26 11:45:11.650 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Mutex created
2018-10-26 11:45:11.870 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Mutex exists
2018-10-26 11:45:11.963 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Mutex exists
2018-10-26 11:45:12.323 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Job started
2018-10-26 11:45:22.633 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Job ended
2018-10-26 11:45:22.947 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - About to release mutex
2018-10-26 11:45:23.290 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Mutex released
```

But if I call it once more after release and close has been called, I just get

```
2018-10-26 11:46:35.133 d6e4dd2e-16f1-43aa-b34b-226187dd9185 - Mutex exists
```

Shouldn't `TryOpenExisting` fail after mutex has been released? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's a rather uncommon requirement for a Web API. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Fildor This is a controller that runs every so and synchronizes data from 3rd party databases with our own.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a `Mutex`, you should consider [Monitor.TryEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Monitor_TryEnter_System_Object_) instead.

It functions like `lock`, but returns immediately (as you want) if the lock is already taken.

To do this, you will need to declare a `static` lock object:

```
private static object lockObject;
```

Or, if you need multiple locks (e.g. per database) then you would store those locks in a:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> lockObjects = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
```

getting the lock object using [GetOrAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_GetOrAdd__1__0_System_Func__0___0__1____0_).

*Also, this **will** not work if you are using a web farm / web garden / load balancer either (since the lock will be process specific). If this is an issue for you, I'd consider using a [queue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-amazon-simple-queue-service-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-delivery-deduplication/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29) - whereby every web server adds entries to the queue and a single queue consumer pulls off the queue and de-dupes the requests.*

Comment: Is it suitable for web api controller? As I understand Monitor lock resources across threads. Isn't there a chance that different request be served by different processes? (The service is hosted on Azure. I have no idea how and when processes are created).

Comment: I don't believe Azure uses web gardens. Thus this should be fine. Note if you run multiple instances then each server / process will get its own (separate) lock.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need logic around whether the Mutex exists or not?

Why not always use `var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName);`? You don't HAVE to check whether it exists or not. And that check of `Mutex.TryOpenExisting` isn't threadsafe either.

EDIT

One more question, do you need a Mutex here, will a LOCK not be sufficient? Are you planning on running multiple instances of this WebAPI on the same server? If not, then a Lock should be sufficient.

`Mutex` - Work across Processes

`Lock` - Work across Threads

Comment: If I use a lock won't the subsequent requests wait on the lock and be executed afterwards? I don't want this. I need the code to never run if it already runs in another request.

Comment: @alfoks That's true, missed that point. If you use Monitor.TryEnter then you can immediately return if it can't acquire the lock.